# как написать media в перевернутом виде в bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

как написать media в  перевернутом виде в bootstrap 4?
col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 так сделал но sm в перевернутом виде не поддерживает
[image: скрин медии]

Comment: Пишите свои запросы: ```@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) { ... } ``` или ```@media screen and (max-width: XXXpx) , screen and (max-height: YYYpx) { ... }``` или ```@media handheld, (min-width: 650px), (orientation: landscape) { ... }```

Comment: чел, уже bootstrap 5, держу в курсе

Comment: Что такое перевёрнутый вид?

Comment: @Qwertiy, наверное речь об ориентации экрана

Comment: @HamSter, но бутстрап никак не взаимодействует с ориентацией.